# recursive method inside loop

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion, return

I want to write a code like this

```
public int recursiveMethod() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (someBool) {
            return recursiveMethod();
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

but this gives compile error `missing return statement`. Is there other way I can achieve this.

**UPDATE** : actual code

```
public static File searchFile(File currentFile) {
    File[] results = null;

    if (currentFile.isDirectory()) {
        for (File file : currentFile.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                return searchFile(file);
            } else {
                results = file.getParentFile().listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".sh");
                    }
                });

                if (results.length > 0) {
                    return results[0];
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        results = currentFile.getParentFile().listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".sh");
            }
        });

        if (results.length > 0) {
            return results[0];
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *We* know that your loop body will run exactly once. The compiler doesn't know that it will run at all. Given that the loop is pointless (you're returning either way), why do you have a loop at all?

Comment: why loop? in first iteration it returns ...

Comment: Maybe he wants the return -1 at the end of the method and not inside the for?

Comment: your method MUST ALWAYS return an int. The compiler thinks that there is a probablity that the method might not return an int.

Comment: this is dummy code. actually my code is to find a file recursively.

Comment: @Darshana: So this code isn't representative of your actual problem. I suggest you post representative code instead, otherwise we can't help you. In particular, you should consider what you want to happen if you *don't* find the file.

Comment: @JonSkeet i think he should consider what he want to happen if he find the file? reversing the logic may help...

Comment: @JonSkeet I update the question with actual code

Comment: @Darshana: Well now you're trying to return a variable which isn't even declared - that *won't* give the error message you described.

Comment: @JonSkeet that was mistake. I tried doing some changes with code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is broken in the way it's looping - you're stopping on the very first iteration, either reporting success or failure. You *should* be continuing to loop until you find something or run out of items to iterate over.

I would change the general structure so that the *last* statement in the method is `return null;` - so any time you can return a positive result, you do so, but otherwise you just let it fall through. So something like this:

```
public static File searchFile(File currentFile) {
    if (!currentFile.isDirectory()) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Starting point must be a directory");
    }
    for (File file : currentFile.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File result = searchFile(file);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        } else if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".sh")) {
            return file;
        }
    }
    // Not found anything: return null to indicate failure (in this branch)
    return null;
}
```

(I've removed the call to `getParentFile()` and restructured the code for simplicity. Now it will *only* accept a directory as the starting point, but that simplifies things greatly, and makes much more sense anyway, IMO.)

Answer (score 0):

what is `someBool`?
You are calling `recursiveMethod()` if someBool is true and everytime `recursiveMethod()` is called, the value of i starts from 0 and goes on calling`recursiveMethod()`.

As mentionned in previous comment, simply putting a return statement at the end of the method does not guarantee you are achieving what you need

Comment: As stated by OP, "this is dummy code. actually my code is to find a file recursively."

Comment: I don't see how this could fix the problem, i mean: you have 192 rep you can post comments..